# How to convert single vector to multiple strings?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a C++ code that takes multiple strings, adds them all to a vector, and sorts them alphabetically but I need it to then split that vector back up and assign the values of it back into individual strings. How can I do this? I have searched all over for assigning a vector to *multiple* strings but have only found going from strings to vectors.

I have the vector "names" and I would like to assign it to multiple strings that correspond to the order the names are in withing the vector "names", for example:

Input:

"John Dave Peter Charlie Michael"

The code splits these up and orders them alphabetically but now I would like to assign them back to the strings "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", etc. for each name withing the vector (the vector will never be exceeding 20 names so for now I'm just defining each string independently).

In the end I would like to be able to add

```
cout << str1 << endl
cout << str2 << endl
```

etc. and get the output:

Charlie

Dave

John

Michael

Peter

(I will be further manipulating the names before displaying them so simply displaying the whole vector right away would not do any good). Thanks a lot!

----edit----

the comment wouldn't let me return, if right now I put in:

```
cout << names[0] << endl
```

I get out:

Charlie

Charlie

Charlie

Charlie

Charlie

----edit----

Current Code:

```
    vector<string> separate_string(const string& input)
{
    istringstream input_stream(input);
    string buffer;
    vector<string> separated;
    while (input_stream >> buffer)
    {
        separated.push_back(buffer);
    }

    return separated;
}

int main()
{
    string test_string;
    getline(cin, test_string);
    auto names = separate_string(test_string);
    //sort(begin(names), end(names));
    //for (const auto& s : names)
        //string temp1;
    cout << names[0] << endl;

}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just index into the vector? `vec[0]`, `vec[1]`, etc., instead of `str1`, `str2`, etc.

Comment: No, that would work as well, I suppose that would make keeping track of them easier.

Comment: I'm fairly new to c++ (as you can probably tell) and actually didn't know you could just do that, so typing "cout << names[0] << endl works fine but how do I make it output only 1? right now I get:

Charlie
Charlie
Charlie
Charlie
Charlie

Comment: Sounds like you repeated that line 5 times?

Comment: Here, I'll post the current code, one sec.

Comment: I commented out some previous things, just ignore them

Comment: @user3052738 - Write a loop.

Comment: `for(const auto & s : names) cout << s << endl;`. `for(const auto & s : names)` already iterates over each element of `names`, so you just need to print `s` out.

Comment: Well what I said in the description Is I need to work with them as individual strings before printing, that for (const auto & s : names) was just there from testing the splitting program.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a container to hold them:

```
vector<string> my_strings {"John", "Dave", "Peter", "Charlie", "Michael"};
```

and then *sort* them:

```
std::sort(my_strings.begin(), my_strings.end());
```

and then *print* to stdout:

```
std::copy(my_strings.begin(), my_strings.end(), std::ostream_iterator<string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I apologize, I think I was confused as to what I really was looking for, I figured out how to do it, I just didn't know about the ability to index the vector (yeah, I'm a complete noob).

I ended up solving it but just defining each string with an index:

```
string test_string;
    getline(cin, test_string);
    auto names = separate_string(test_string);
    //sort(begin(names), end(names));
    //for (const auto& s : names)
    string temp1 = names[0];
        cout << temp1 << endl;
    string temp2 = names[1];
        cout << temp2 << endl;
    string temp3 = names[2];
        cout << temp3 << endl;
    string temp4 = names[3];
        cout << temp4 << endl;
```

And of course I'm just printing them right away now to test to make sure it's assigning properly, I can now move on to actually coding how I actually want it to manipulate the names.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: So if you had 1,000 strings, you would write 1,000 individual `cout` statements?  A good programmer finds patterns in their code, and instead of copying and pasting the same code over and over again with minor differences, they find a way to do this generically.